# get indexes of elements containig some value and the coresponding elements from another list

Tags: scala, list

The queston is a mouthful, but the idea pretty simple.

I have 3 lists and a string.

```
val a = List("x", "y", "z")
val b = List("a1", "a2", "b1", "b2", "c1", "c2", "d1", "d2")
val c = List("1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4")
val d = "xc1b1"
```

I need to check if `d` contains elements from `a`. If it does I check the position of all the elemtns from `b` that are present in `d` and return a set of elements from `c` that corespond these positions.

The result for the given example is

```
Set("3", "2")
```

But when I try

```
if(a.exists(d.contains)) c(b.indexWhere(d.contains))
```

I only get

```
Any = 2
```

Which corespond to the first encountered elemnt from `b` ie `b1`

How would I get the set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-

```
if(a.exists(d.contains)) b.zip(c).collect{ 
    case (x, y) if d.contains(x) => y 
}
// res1: Any = List(2, 3)
```

If you need a Set:

```
if(a.exists(d.contains)) b.zip(c).collect{ 
    case (x, y) if d.contains(x) => y 
}.toSet
// res2: Any = Set(2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I've understood what you need to do here, although the question could do with some clarification.

These are the two ways of getting to your set that I found:

`if(a.exists(d.contains)) b.collect { 
  case x if d.contains(x) => c(b.indexOf(x)) 
}.toSet`

`if(a.exists(d.contains)) b.filter(d.contains).map(b.indexOf).map(c).toSet`

Both find elements of b that are in d, then find their index in b and find their relative elements in c. The first way is more explicit in what it's doing, while the second way is more concise.